# Difference between pthread_exit(PTHREAD_CANCELED) and pthread_cancel(pthread_self())

Tags: pthreads, signals

When `pthread_exit(PTHREAD_CANCELED)` is called I have expected behavior (stack unwinding, destructors calls) but the call to `pthread_cancel(pthread_self())` just terminated the thread.

Why `pthread_exit(PTHREAD_CANCELED)` and `pthread_cancel(pthread_self())` differ significantly and the thread memory is not released in the later case?

The background is as follows:

The calls are made from a signal handler and reasoning behind this strange approach is to cancel a thread waiting for the external library `semop()` to complete (looping around on `EINTR` I suppose)

I have noticed that calling `pthread_cancel` from other thread does not work (as if `semop` was not a cancellation point) but signalling the thread and then calling `pthread_exit` works but calls the destructor within a signal handler.
`pthread_cancel` could postpone the action to the next cancellation point.

Comment: Where is the question? :)

Comment: It might be of interest for you that calling `pthread_testcancel()` is is possible to explicitly introduce a cancellation point.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of thread specific clean-up behaviour there should be no difference between cancelling a thread via `pthread_cancel()` and exiting a thread via `pthread_exit()`.

[POSIX says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_cancel.html):

> [...] When the cancellation is acted on, the cancellation clean-up handlers for thread shall be called. When the last cancellation clean-up handler returns, the thread-specific data destructor functions shall be called for thread. When the last destructor function returns, thread shall be terminated.

---

From Linux's [`man pthread_cancel`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cancel.3.html):

> When a cancellation requested is acted on, the following steps occur for thread (in this order):
>
> 1. Cancellation clean-up handlers are popped (in the reverse of the order in which they were pushed) and called.  (See pthread_cleanup_push(3).)
> 2. Thread-specific data destructors are called, in an unspecified order.  (See pthread_key_create(3).)
> 3. The thread is terminated.  (See pthread_exit(3).)

---

Referring the strategy to introduce a cancellation point by signalling a thread, I have my doubts this were the cleanest way.

As many system calls return on receiving a signal while setting `errno` to `EINTR`, it would be easy to catch this case and simply let the thread end itself cleanly under this condition via `pthread_exit()`.

Some pseudo code:

```
while (some condition) 
{
  if (-1 == semop(...))
  { /* getting here on error or signal reception */
    if (EINTR == errno)
    { /* getting here on signal reception */
      pthread_exit(...);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Turned out that there is no difference. 
However some interesting side effects took place.

Operations on `std::iostream` especially cerr/cout include cancellation points. When the underlying operation is canceled the stream is marked as not good. So you will get no output from any other thread if only one has discovered cancellation on an attempt to print.

So play with `pthread_setcancelstate()` and `pthread_testcancel()` or just call `cerr.clear()` when needed.

Applies to C++ streams only, stderr,stdin seems not be affected.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there are two things associated to thread which will tell what to do when you call pthread_cancel().

```
1. pthread_setcancelstate
2. pthread_setcanceltype
```

first function will tell whether that particular thread can be cancelled or not, and the second function tells when and how that thread should be cancelled, for example, should that thread be terminated as soon as you send cancellation request or it need to wait till that thread reaches some milestone before getting terminated.

when you call pthread_cancel(), thread wont be terminated directly, above two actions will be performed, i.e., checking whether that thread can be cancelled or not, and if yes, when to cancel.

if you disable cancel state, then pthread_cancel() can't terminate that thread, but the cancellation request will stay in a queue waiting for that thread to become cancellable, i.e., at some point of time if you are enabling cancel state, then your cancel request will start working on terminating that thread

whereas if you use pthread_exit(), then the thread will be terminated irrespective to the cancel state and cancel type of that particular thread.

*this is one of the differences between pthread_exit() and pthread_cancel(), there can be few more.